# Can you configure Windows to open JAR files like ZIP files without a 3rd party tool?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, java, zip, jar

I'd like to be able to examine the contents of a JAR file without having to install Winzip or some other tool and without having to rename the file.  Windows Explorer can open ZIP files just fine; is there some registry setting I can use to let it treat JARs like ZIPs?

Comment: i wonder why this was migrated.  why would anyone but a programmer be interested in this.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Or from the command line:

```
assoc .jar=CompressedFolder
```

Under **Vista** (*or higher*) you have to run this in an elevated Command Prompt.

Comment: NB: for Vista and above, you'll probably need to run the command prompt with elevated privileges i.e. as Administrator.

Comment: works on Windows 8 as well +1. Thanks!

Comment: Also works on Windows 10 in CMD. Does not work in PowerShell. While you're doing this, I suggest you do it with .ear and .war, too.

Comment: Also, `assoc .jar=jarfile` to restore

Answer (score 4):

I tried exporting HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.zip, changing all references of '.zip' to '.jar' and importing it to HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.jar.

Under Vista at least it let me open a .jar file as if it were a .zip.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is associate the JAR extension in Windows Explorer with Compressed folders.  From Windows Explorer select tools / Folder Options.  Then the Files Types tab.  Select New and associate JAR Compressed (ZIP) Folder.

Answer (score 0):

The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT trick doesnt work under Windows 7.  There mut be some compelling reason that MSFT doesnt want us to do this.

Comment: Worked fine for me under Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

In setting up a new Windows 10 machine this was the reason I used to install 7-zip but there is no need with this hack given by @hfrmobile.

1. Press <kbd>WinKey</kbd> and type cmd
2. Right click *Command Prompt* app and select *Run as administrator*
3. Type *assoc .jar=CompressedFolder*, it should be echoed back to the screen if accepted otherwise you will get an access is denied
4. Type *assoc .ear=CompressedFolder*
5. Type *assoc .war=CompressedFolder*
6. Right click a jar in Windows explorer and you should now see the *Extract All...* menu option available to zip files