# View the contents of Jars files?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, zip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you configure Windows to open JAR files like ZIP files without a 3rd party tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/121540/can-you-configure-windows-to-open-jar-files-like-zip-files-without-a-3rd-party-t)

How i can view the contents of Jar files and enter to it like Zip files on windows 7 , so windows explorer can view these files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this registry script:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\.jar]
@="CompressedFolder"
```

Comment: For more information about this apparently undocumented `@` symbol, don't bother with the official MS docs, because it's not mentioned there.  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310516  Apparently it refers to the `Data` field of the `(Default)` key.

Answer (score 1):

Jar (=Java Archive) are just zipped Java class files, so you can use any Zip-Archiver tool to unzip it, for example [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

It won't bring you much, however, because class files are the files compiled into bytecode, so this is a binary format you cannot easily look in. You can decompile these files using some of existing Java decompilers, for example [this one](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/).

Answer (score 0):

Open them with [7-zip](http://www.7-zip.org/). If you really want to double click, set it as default program for `.jar` files.

Comment: I do it but it gives me an error message "failed to load main-class manifest attribute " when i opens the file

Comment: -1. This guy wanted Explorer integration.