# Can I make windows open renamed zip files in explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, zip

I have some files on my system (extension `.sublime-package`). These files are nothing but a `.zip` with a different file extension. I can currently browse them by renaming the file, then double clicking to open with the explorer zip viewer.

Is there something I can enter in the "open with" dialog to persuade windows to open the original files with its default zip viewer?

Comment: When you double-click those files what normally happens? Are they associated with Sublime Text? If not do you want to associate them by default with the Compressed Folders feature?

Comment: An open with dialog appears; no, they are not; yes, i do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The terms to look for are

- associate
- CompressedFolder

An equivalent question was asked in *[Can you configure Windows to open JAR files like ZIP files without a 3rd party tool?](https://superuser.com/questions/121540/can-you-configure-windows-to-open-jar-files-like-zip-files-without-a-3rd-party-t)*, using this command for `.jar` files:

```
assoc .jar=CompressedFolder
```

from the command-line, using elevated privileges since it updates the registry.  You could use the same method for associating the `.sublime-package` file type with `CompressedFolder`:

```
assoc .sublime-package=CompressedFolder
```

Microsoft documents the `assoc` program in several places, e.g., [*How to Use the Assoc Command to Change File Associations*](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/184082) .  It has been available since Windows 2000, at least.

In *[Associate .zip extension to which Windows 7 program?](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-windows_programs/associate-zip-extension-to-which-windows-7-program/9122a011-8153-4cd7-a0b4-0e0aa46a2d5b)*, the answer points to a page containing registry fixes (not what you need), but providing an illustration of what is stored in the registry.  For [zip-files](http://www.winhelponline.com/fileasso/zip_fix_w7.reg), it updates several keys in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CompressedFolder`.